Can I masquerade traffic coming over a veth pair without a bridge?
I have created a veth pair with one end of the pair in a net namespace. I assigned the address 10.1.2.50/24 to the side of the pair that is within the namespace, and 10.1.2.1/24 to the side that is in the root namespace. I set up an iptables rule to masquerade traffic from the subnet associated with the veth pair with:
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.1.2.0/24 ! -o my-veth -j MASQUERADE

Does this sound sensible? Can I masquerade traffic coming over a veth pair without creating a bridge?
From outside the namespace I can ping 10.1.2.50 and from within the namespace, I can ping both 10.1.2.1 and also the host's public IP. But from within the namespace I cannot ping public IPs on the internet (it hangs forever waiting for a response). How might I debug?
My setup is as follows. I created the pair like this:
ip link add my-veth type veth peer name my-ceth

I put one end of the pair in a namespace:
ip link set my-ceth netns my-ns

I assigned IP addresses inside and outside the namespace:
ip addr add 10.1.2.1/24 dev my-veth
nsenter --net=/run/netns/my-ns ip addr add 10.1.2.50/24 dev my-ceth

I brought up the devices inside and outside the namespace:
ip link set my-veth up
nsenter --net=/run/netns/my-ns ip link set my-ceth up

I set a default route within the namespace:
nsenter --net=/run/netns/my-ns ip route add default via 10.1.2.1

I created an iptables rule outside the namespace to NAT traffic from the namespace:
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.1.2.0/24 ! -o my-veth -j MASQUERADE

My ip addr looks like this:
133: my-veth@if132: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f6:b9:cb:fe:44:4a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netns my-ns
    inet 10.1.2.1/24 scope global my-veth
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::f4b9:cbff:fefe:444a/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

And inside the namespace:
132: my-ceth@if133: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e2:c6:18:68:c8:14 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 10.1.2.50/24 scope global my-ceth
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

My ip route looks like this:
default via 192.168.88.1 dev wlo1 proto dhcp metric 600 
10.1.2.0/24 dev my-veth proto kernel scope link src 10.1.2.1 

And inside the namespace:
default via 10.1.2.1 dev my-ceth 
10.1.2.0/24 dev my-ceth proto kernel scope link src 10.1.2.50 

And my iptables -t nat --list-rules outside the namespace looks like this:
-P PREROUTING ACCEPT
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
-N DOCKER
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.1.2.0/24 ! -o my-veth -j MASQUERADE
-A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN

Yet I cannot ping public IPs from inside the namespace:
$ sudo ip netns exec my-ns ping 93.184.215.14
PING 93.184.215.14 (93.184.215.14) 56(84) bytes of data.

Any help much appreciated!
